# img path in css error when building the application on webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

My project work with css modules and url-loader from images.
And on localhost all work fine.
I import my styles from my components in react/

When i try build my app on webpack, i get error during the build css, like this
from all images in my styles

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/spinner.gif'
```

If i use `css-loader?url=false` build work without errors, but react not connected and also dont have imgs

my loaders for images

```
{
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
  },
  {
    test: /\.gif/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif"
  },
  {
    test: /\.jpg/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg"
  },
  {
    test: /\.png/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png"
  }
```

and my loader sass/css in build config

```
loaders.push({
  test: /\.sass$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader', use : 'css-loader?sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded'}),
  exclude: ['node_modules']
});
```

and my file tree

[image]

How fix this?

Comment: Can you show us your file tree ? It will help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @ChrisR screenshot or better to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that `App.jsx` is your entry point (or `index.jsx`, it doesn't change anything), so you should import or require your `spinner.gif` like this `./img/spinner.gif` instead of `../img/spinner.gif`.

With the later, you go up a level in the file tree but img and App.jsx are at the same level.

Comment: mm, dot think so, i try add ../ path or ./, and absolute project root path, but this not help

Comment: Which file is the one trying to resolve '../img/spinner.gif'?

Comment: this errors in my styles, all error images are used as background image in sass files and exported to the main sass file, then in build its convert to css and on convert process, i think has error

Comment: In that case, you'll need to write the path to the gifs relatively to the main.sass => try something like: ../src/img/spinner.gif

Comment: omg! its work, before i rty witch ~ symbol, and this is not work, but now all build without error!
But now new trobule, react dont connect or i think routers, if my global components build